# How to assign '\'(-inf-24.5]\'' to a python string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
s='\'(-inf-24.5]\'' #this in not working
```

what should be put before \ to include it?
we have to assign s '\'(-inf-24.5]\''
the last two characters are two single quotes and not a single double quote.
the string should literally contain the given single backslashes as the string is to be inserted as it is in a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> s="\\'(-inf-24.5]\\'"
>>> print s
\'(-inf-24.5]\'
```

or

```
>>> s="'\\'(-inf-24.5]\\''"
>>> print s
'\'(-inf-24.5]\''
```

Basically, you will need to escape the backslash, when you write `\'` normally, python treats it as the `'` being escaped. Also, python strings can be either `""`, or `''`, so you can mix them togather to get the desired result.

Comment: The problem is i have to assign this to values in a column,which need to have only a single \.

Comment: @DiscoDancer What do you mean by assigning in a column? There is no mention of this in the original question...

Comment: @DiscoDancer do you know how escaping works? It does say that `s="\\'(-inf-24.5]\\'"` but the actual string `s` will have only one slash at the start and one at the end

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = r"'\'(-inf-24.5]\''"
>>> s
"'\\'(-inf-24.5]\\''"
>>> print(s)
'\'(-inf-24.5]\''
```

Prepending `r` before a string denotes a raw string, basically indicating to the interpreter that that string's characters should be taken literally. The only thing it can't do is end a string with a backslash (such a backslash would have to be concatenated from a separate string).